# Is there a wait/sleep function in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I tried to find a wait/sleep/pause function in freemarker, but couldn't find anything on page 1 of Google or the Freemarker documentation. Does anyone know if this exists, or if there's a workaround that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker doesn't have wait function, FreeMarker is a server-side compiled UI templating language which means the code you write gets compiled and the result is sent to the UI.

See documentation for more: https://freemarker.apache.org/

If you want to have sleep then considers javascript `setTimeout()` function or jQuery's `sleep` function. You cam mix javascript/jQuery easily with FreeMarker.